# Как получить обратно RESTful запрос?

Tags: java, spring, maven, rest

Только знакомлюсь со Spring. Необходимо сделать данный туториал - https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/. Написал половину кода, что там дано. И в середине туториала нам предлагают запустить проект и посмотреть, что уже получилось! Получиться должно вот что:

```java
{
  "_embedded": {
    "employeeList": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bilbo Baggins",
        "role": "burglar",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/employees/1"
          },
          "employees": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/employees"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Frodo Baggins",
        "role": "thief",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/employees/2"
          },
          "employees": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/employees"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/employees"
    }
  }
}
```

Вместо этого при наборе адреса http://localhost:8080/employees я получаю следующее:

```java
[{"id":1,"name":"Bilbo Baggins","role":"burglar"},{"id":2,"name":"Frodo Baggins","role":"thief"}]
```

Всего классов 7, и, соответственно, во избежание каши и для удобства читателя, решил добавить код на `GitHub`.
https://github.com/Rogue06/demonica

Comment: А что не так? Вам не нравится, что json в одну строчку?

Comment: ну я подумал раз в туториале не так, то наверно я что-то ошибочно делаю.

Comment: я правильно понимаю, это как-то связано с pretty print?

Comment: @Aryur Vartanyan  Да, все так)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всего лишь надо добавить `pretty print` в конфигурации `Spring`.